# Query AD for active users

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I want to create a script to identify AD users which are valid in an active directory via ldap. The problem is I don't know what means valid users in an active directory exactly...

Imagine we have a list of windows logins. We want to query if a user is able to login. That means the account is not expired, is not inactive, ... what else?

```
res = l.search_s("DC=...",
                 ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                 '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))' % sAMAccountName,
                 ['lastlogon','accountExpires', 'cn', 'mail', 'lockoutTime'])
```

My script becomes more and more complex with if-else-if-else. I look for a clear and transparent way to query: Is a user currently able to login?

Comment: Maybe you are over-thinking this.  If I understand you correctly, all you need is a list of all non-disabled users, who have logged into the domain within the last XX number of days?

Comment: @T-Heron Yes, maybe... yes, non-disabled users, not expired, logged in during last year. Beside that I don't know if I miss something...

Answer (score 1):

After further research :

You should use :

- [LastLogonTimeStamp](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LastLogonTimeStamp) which is the time stamp : compare to timestamp from 1year ago
- [AccountExpires](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/AccountExpires) : value of 0 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) indicates that the account never expires.
- lockoutTime : `(lockoutTime=>0)` : It is the timestamp when the account was locked, so if it's set it's locked *(Search ldapwiki.com for more informations as 
  I can't put more than 2 links in a post ;) )*

---

I don't know very well ActiveDirectory, but wouldn't it be easier to make all these tests in the ldap filter?

Something like that *(need to be adapted, corresponding to the attributes LDAP syntax)* :

```
(&
  (objectClass = user)
  (sAMAccountName = %s)
  (lastlogon < dateFrom1Year)
  (!(accountExpires = *))
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `need to be adapted, corresponding to the attributes LDAP syntax` that's the problem. :) Either in LDAP or Python...